# Why minus sign cannot be read correctly in my Antlr grammar

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I have written the following Antlr grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
file: row+ ;
row: karyotype NEWLINE ;
karyotype: chrNum (',' sexChr CONST?)? (',' event)* ;
event: prefixPlus gainChr (CONST | INH)?       # gainChrEvent
     | prefixMinus lossChr (CONST | INH)?      # lossChrEvent
     ;
chrNum: numRangeTypeI ;
numRangeTypeI: INT (APPROX INT)? ;
gainChr: INT | SEX ;
lossChr: INT | SEX ;
prefixPlus: PLUS QUES? | QUES PLUS ;
prefixMinus: MINUS QUES? | QUES MINUS ; 
sexChr: (SEX | QUES)+ ;

APPROX:  '~' | '-' ;
CONST: 'c' ;
INH: 'dn' | 'inh' | 'mat' | 'pat' ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;
MINUS: '-' ;
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' ;
PLUS: '+' ;
QUES: '?' ;
SEX: [XY]+ ;

WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

But when I use the following for parsing:

```
43-45,XX,-4
```

The Antlr told me "line 1:9 mismatched input '-' expecting {'-', '+', '?'}"

Do you know what's wrong with my grammar? [image: The grun -gui parse-tree picture has been attached.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `APPROX` and `MINUS` rules are mutually ambiguous. Try with these changes:

```
numRangeTypeI: INT ((APPROX | MINUS) INT)? ;

APPROX:  '~' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why. After changing

```
APPROX:  '~' | '-' ;
```

to

```
approx:  '~' | MINUS ;
```

My code is working now!

Actually, The Definite ANTLR4 Reference says in p. 280, "Be careful that you don’t specify the same string literal on the right side of multiple lexer rules. Such literals are ambiguous and could match multiple token types."